# Transmural pressure

Tags: pressure, soft-question

Transmural pressure

I want to ask about transmural pressure. For example, if the pressure outside a balloon increases, the volume decreases, and if the pressure decreases, the volume goes up. But what if the inside pressure increases and the outside pressure is constant, or if the inside pressure and the outside pressure are constant, what happens to the volume then? What is the relationship between the outside and inside pressure and volume?

Comment: The answer depends on the properties of the material of which the wall is made. It will be different for a perfectly elastic balloon (tension increases with size) vs a soap bubble (constant tension, reducing curvature: reduced pressure difference). Which do you have?

Comment: elastic balloon (tension increases with size)

Comment: Section 4.1.4 in [this link](http://solidmechanics.org/text/Chapter4_1/Chapter4_1.htm) gives you the full derivation for an elastic sphere of finite thickness. It may be more than you need to know... when the sphere is very thin the equations simplify quite a bit. I don't have time to give you a summary right now - let me know if you have any questions after looking at that.

Answer (score 0):

The term *transmural* more often associated with differential pressure across the tissues, walls of an organ or vasculature body. Since tissues normally have compliance (or inversely elastance) then you can expect the structures to expand or contract according to the pressure *difference*. It's the sign of this difference that determines expansion or contraction.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at section 4.1.4 in [this article](http://solidmechanics.org/text/Chapter4_1/Chapter4_1.htm), they give the tangential stress in the wall of a sphere with radius from $a$ to $b$, internal pressure $p_a$ and external pressure $p_b$, as

$$\sigma_{\theta \theta} = \frac{p_a a^3 - p_b b^3}{b^3-a^3} + \frac{(p_a-p_b)a^3b^3}{2(b^3-a^3)r^3}$$

Where $r$ is the distance from the center of the sphere.

If we assume a thin shell of radius $R$ and thickness $b-a=\delta\ll R$, then $b^3-a^3 = 3\delta R^2$ and we can simplify the above to

$$\begin{align}\sigma_{\theta \theta} &= \frac{(p_a - p_b)R^3}{3\delta R^2} + \frac{(p_a-p_b)R^3}{6\delta R^2}\\
&=\frac{(p_a-p_b)R}{2\delta}\end{align}$$

This can be easily seen by realizing that the force due to the pressure is $\pi R^2 (p_a-p_b) $ and that it is distributed over an area $2\pi R \delta$; the stress in the sphere is just the ratio of the force over the area, $\frac{\Delta P \pi R^2}{2\pi R \delta}=\frac{\Delta P R}{2\delta}$, which is what we got from the above expression.

At some radius $R_0$, there is no elastic deformation and the pressure difference is zero. As you increase the internal pressure, the sphere (balloon) will have to expand - the new radius will be such that the stress in the balloon divided by the strain equals the elastic modulus. Now we already have an expression for the stress; the strain is given by the square root of the increase in area (because you stretch the material in two directions) - so it is linear in the increased radius. Putting all that together, we can now compute the pressure inside a balloon of radius $R$ with an unstretched radius of $R_0$.

The strain:

$$\frac{\Delta R}{R_0} = \frac{R-R_0}{R_0}$$

The stress:

$$\sigma = \frac{R \Delta P}{2\delta}$$

and the Young's modulus:

$$E = \rm{\frac{stress}{strain}}=\frac{R \cdot R_0\Delta P}{R-R_0}$$

Rearranging, we get $\Delta P$ as a function of $R$:

$$\Delta P = \frac{E(R-R_0)}{R\cdot R_0} $$

I created a simple plot to show how the pressure will initially increase rapidly with size, then slows down as the radius gets bigger:

[image]

In real balloons, this is significantly complicated by the fact that as the rubber stretches (especially for the first time), significant nonlinear effects come into play; but I don't think that's what your question was about.

Obviously you can express the above expressions in terms of the volume, $V = \frac43 \pi R^3$. I hope this helps.